# How to properly set the solr configuration for a config friendly data location

Tags: solr

I'm working with a solr app that needs to have a config friendly data location. I've been following [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml) post with no luck.

In my solr module I have the following solrcore.properties file

```
#solrcore.properties
data.dir=C:\temp\solr123\
```

I also have the following defined in my solrconfig (also in the solr module)

```
<dataDir>${data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>
```

solr is still creating the solr directory in the root directory so it would appear that the config friendly property can't be found.

Anyone actually hooked these up so you could config your data dir dynamically with solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We defined the following system property when starting up our container.

```
-Dsystem.properties=conf\solrcore.properties
```

solrcore.properties had the following property

```
data.dir=C:\\temp\\document-imaging\\solr
```

In our pom we added a system property section for running our maven build.

```
<systemProperties>  
    <system.properties>${tomcat.basedir}/conf/override.properties</system.properties>
</systemProperties>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to verify that setting data.dir in solrcore.properties does work, but I tested this on OS X in Jetty. I'm not sure what web container you're using, but you might want to try defining

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=<location of solr>
```

since solrcore.properties is expected to be in

```
 <solr.home>/conf/solrcore.properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify further more.

The `solrcore.properties` file (Solr 4.x) should be placed either in `conf/` or `collection1/conf` directory of your Solr home or if Tomcat is used, it can be placed in `WEB-INF/` dir of your app. Basically anywhere within Java *classpath*.

If Solr 5.x is used, consider using [`core.properties`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) instead.

Then the configuration can be either reloaded from Application Manager (`/manager/html`) or Solr/Jetty/Tomcat service needs to be restarted.